# How to open tabtip keyboard in a custom location?

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, location, customization

How can I open the tabtip keyboard in a custom location?

This is my code:

```
Private tabtipProcess As Process

Private Sub t_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    tabtipProcess = Process.Start("tabtip")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finally testing my previous answer I can confirm that (as you said) it doesn't work, so I did some research.

There are a few others that have also wanted to change its location, so after reading a few posts and after I performed some testing myself, it would seem that the `tabtip` application has been designed to trap certain window messages (more specifically [**WM_MOVE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632631(v=vs.85).aspx) and/or [**WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653(v=vs.85).aspx) and [**WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632652(v=vs.85).aspx)) which makes you unable to change its location or size programmatically using the standard methods.

At this point there doesn't seem to be a way to modify its location.

Comment: thanks. so what can I use for virtual  keyboard. I want a keyboard that be can change input language?

Comment: @RahmanJalayer : Well tabtip would've done it. Do you really need to change its position instead of letting it start in the center of the screen? If so you would have to either find a third party application or build one on your own.

Comment: @RahmanJalayer : I have undeleted my previous answer so you can use that as a reference in case you start using a third party keyboard. -- There's for example [**Hot Virtual Keyboard**](http://hot-virtual-keyboard.com/).

Answer (score 0):

### [Undeleted answer to provide a solution if the OP decides to use a third party application instead]

***- For the record, you cannot seem to programmatically change the location of tabtip.***

You can P/Invoke (also known as [**Platform Invoke**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services)) the WinAPI's [**`SetWindowPos()` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) and send your process's [**`MainWindowHandle`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) to it. Then you just specify the coordinates where you want to put the window.

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

Const SWP_NOSIZE As Integer = &H0001

Private tabtipProcess As Process

Private Sub t_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    tabtipProcess = Process.Start("tabtip")
    tabtipProcess.WaitForInputIdle()
    SetWindowPos(tabtipProcess.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 300, 200, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE)
End Sub
```

The above example will put the window at coordinates (300, 200).

The [**`tabtipProcess.WaitForInputIdle()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2(v=vs.110).aspx) call is necessary as it is used to wait until the application has finished loading and a window handle has been created. Without it `tabtipProcess.MainWindowHandle` will most likely return `0` and result in an error when calling the `SetWindowPos()` function.

Passing the `SWP_NOSIZE` flag tells the function that the window should retain its current size.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it's not work for me!!! the location doesn't change. :( .  I copy these code in my program. but the location of tabtip no change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by altering the registry values of the tabtip.

Like this:

```
 My.Computer.Registry.SetValue(
    "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7",
    "OptimizedKeyboardRelativeXPositionOnScreen",
    &HDB1D,
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord
)
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue(
    "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7", 
    "OptimizedKeyboardRelativeYPositionOnScreen",
    &H12016,
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord
)
```

The two hex values are the locations of your x and y.

Geoff.